# Maven : unable to find java.lang issue on OS X

Tags: java, macos, maven, runtime

I getting the below issue when I tried `mvn clean install`
obviously it is unable to find the run time jar but what I need to do ?

the error log :

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failure executing javac, but could not parse the error:
[parsing started /Users/olgunkaya/workspace/CM2H/remoteaccess/osgi/ag.ra.common/src/main/java/com/ericsson/research/ag/ra/common/cthserverclient/IHttpClient.java]
[parsing completed 42ms]
[parsing started /Users/olgunkaya/workspace/CM2H/remoteaccess/osgi/ag.ra.common/src/main/java/com/ericsson/research/ag/ra/common/cthserverclient/CTHWebSessionException.java]
[parsing completed 1ms]
[parsing started /Users/olgunkaya/workspace/CM2H/remoteaccess/osgi/ag.ra.common/src/main/java/com/ericsson/research/ag/ra/common/cthserverclient/CTHServerSession.java]
[parsing completed 14ms]
[search path for source files: /Users/olgunkaya/workspace/CM2H/remoteaccess/osgi/ag.ra.common/src/main/java,]
[search path for class files: /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/rt.jar,/Users/olgunkaya/workspace/CM2H/remoteaccess/osgi/ag.ra.common/target/classes,/Users/olgunkaya/.m2/repository/json/json-simple/1.1/json-simple-1.1.jar,.]
Fatal Error: Unable to find package java.lang in classpath or bootclasspath

[INFO] 1error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.696s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Jun 11 07:54:00 EEST 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 5M/81M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3:compile > (default-compile) on project ag.ra.common: Compilation failure
[ERROR] Failure executing javac, but could not parse the error:
[ERROR] [parsing started /Users/olgunkaya/workspace/CM2H/remoteaccess/osgi/ag.ra.common/src/main/java/com/ericsson/research/ag/ra/common/cthserverclient/IHttpClient.java]
[ERROR] [parsing completed 42ms]
[ERROR] [parsing started /Users/olgunkaya/workspace/CM2H/remoteaccess/osgi/ag.ra.common/src/main/java/com/ericsson/research/ag/ra/common/cthserverclient/CTHWebSessionException.java]
[ERROR] [parsing completed 1ms]
[ERROR] [parsing started /Users/olgunkaya/workspace/CM2H/remoteaccess/osgi/ag.ra.common/src/main/java/com/ericsson/research/ag/ra/common/cthserverclient/CTHServerSession.java]
[ERROR] [parsing completed 14ms]
[ERROR] [search path for source files: /Users/olgunkaya/workspace/CM2H/remoteaccess/osgi/ag.ra.common/src/main/java,]
[ERROR] [search path for class files: /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/rt.jar,/Users/olgunkaya/workspace/CM2H/remoteaccess/osgi/ag.ra.common/target/classes,/Users/olgunkaya/.m2/repository/json/json-simple/1.1/json-simple-1.1.jar,.]
[ERROR] Fatal Error: Unable to find package java.lang in classpath or bootclasspath
```

Comment: is ur java installed properly? if yes is it at same location where this command is trying to search(i.e. "System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/rt.jar") ?

Comment: mac os x lion comes with its own java installed on. The problem is; as I know oraclhe hasn't been provided a java for MAC. Apple is using own java for it. 

And in that java no rt.jar is provided. I think it is something different name. But I am not sure.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think I found the issue.

Apple has changed the rt.jar to classes.jar which is located in.

/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/`<your_java_version>`/Classes/classes.jar

I need to modify my pom.xml to show it the path to classes.jar.

Edit : In a multi-mudule project. Creating soft links to classes jar in the lib directory is much better.

```
sudo ln -s ../../Classes/classes.jar ./rt.jar
```

Well `sudo` because writing in the result of `/usr/libexec/java_home`command ,which is your java home directory, requires administrator priviligies.

Comment: When I tried this to fix a similar problem I had, the above command needed to be run from $JAVA_HOME/lib in order for Maven to find it.

Comment: it is actually depends on which java version are you using. once I had this issue, Oracle had not implemented Java for OS X. Nowadays I don't think one need to do this operation (unless (s)he is not using java 1.6 or lower)