# mvn compile: Unable to find package java.lang

Tags: java, maven

I have maven-compiler-plugin settings below:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
        <compilerArguments>
            <bootclasspath>${java.home}/lib/rt.jar;${java.home}/lib/jce.jar</bootclasspath>
        </compilerArguments>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

When executing `mvn compile`, it reports `Unable to find package java.lang in classpath or bootclasspath`. But I do find `java.lang` package in `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar`:

```
java/lang/Thread$UncaughtExceptionHandler.class
java/lang/ThreadGroup.class
java/lang/Runnable.class
java/lang/Thread.class
java/lang/ref/Finalizer.class
java/lang/ref/PhantomReference.class
java/lang/ref/FinalReference.class
java/lang/ref/WeakReference.class
java/lang/ref/SoftReference.class
java/lang/ref/Reference.class
......
```

I'm using Oracle JDK 1.8 on OS X 10.11.3. What extra info should I provide? Is the problem from JDK or project's maven setting?

edit:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8/Contents/Home
```

edit2:

Different from [Maven : unable to find java.lang issue on OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10974684/maven-unable-to-find-java-lang-issue-on-os-x), I'm using **Oracle JDK**

edit3:

maven version

```
Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-11T00:41:47+08:00)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.3.9/libexec
Java version: 1.8.0_60, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.11.3", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8/Contents/Home` is a soft link to `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home` shown in maven version info

Comment: don't you need to set JAVA_HOME?

Comment: @ObiWan-PallavJha It is set in shell: `export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8/Contents/Home
`

Comment: @ObiWan-PallavJha I've also tried source and target with JDK 1.8, same problem

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10974684/maven-unable-to-find-java-lang-issue-on-os-x)

Comment: @haihui No, I'm using Oracle JDK, not Apple

Comment: Can you edit in the output from `mvn --version`, please?

Comment: @hbprotoss thanks. BTW, did you restart the shell window after setting the export?

Comment: @Dropout JAVA_HOME was set long ago, the problem appeared on a newly developed project transferred to me by other developers

Comment: @RC. After removing the bootclasspath arg, it reports `package com.sun.image.codec.jpeg does not exist` which is used in the project

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`<compilerArguments>` is deprecated, but that's not why it's not working. These types of arguments only work if `<fork>` is set to `true`.

This works for me:

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
   <configuration>
     <source>1.8</source>
     <target>1.8</target>
     <fork>true</fork>
     <compilerArgs>
       <arg>-bootclasspath</arg>
       <arg>${java.home}/lib/rt.jar${path.separator}${java.home}/lib/jce.jar</arg>
     </compilerArgs>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: BTW, why does it have to run in a separate process? From `mvn compile -X`, it does pass `-bootclasspath /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar;/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar` to the command line options

Comment: Because internally, Maven uses `javax.tools.JavaCompiler` by default and it uses it in-process. Obviously, this compiler doesn't have as many bells and whistles as `javac`, but it does just fine for 99% of its use-cases. For the remaining use-cases (like yours), the plugin allows you to use `javac` but since it's not the compiler it uses _directly_, the plugin will fork a process instead.